# Get first record per identifier group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, distinct

```
Code     Description     Whatever
---------------------------------
1        stuff           blah
1        something       meh
2        yah             bong
2        never           hammer time
```

How do I get a results set from this with each `Code` only present once? (I don't overly care which record for that code it is).

So I want....

```
1        stuff           blah
2        yah             bong
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT * , row_number() over(partition by code order by Description) as id
from yourTable
) temp
WHERE id = 1
```

I think this is sql server only

Answer (score 0):

You first need to pick a column which determines what counts as 'the first result'. In my example I chose `Description`:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable first 
WHERE 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable previous 
    WHERE previous.Code=first.Code AND previous.Description < first.Description) = 0
```